Auditing in .NET 6 with Audit.NET library and Audit.NET.Serilog
I am currently the below library in my DotNET 6 WebAPI project for logging incoming Http Requests
Audit.NET
Audit.WebApi.Core
Audit.NET.Serilog
I used the sample code provided in the links above but I am getting a compile time error (Attached screenshot for reference). Not sure if I am missing any reference. I have tried looking up online for solution with no avail.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Compile Error
Edit: Including code snippet as suggested
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
 .UseSerilog(config => config
 .Logger(ev => LogManager.GetLogger(ev.EventType))
 .LogLevel(ev => ev.Environment.Exception != null ? Audit.Serilog.LogLevel.Fatal : Audit.Serilog.LogLevel.Info));

The error I get is "The name LogManager" does not exist in the current context.

Post code and errors as text, not images. Images can't be googled, copied, compiled or tested. Besides, request logging isn't auditing and is already included in Serilog.AspNetCore which I assume you already use

As mentioned in the comment by @panagiotis-kanavos, you could use the Serilog.AspNetCore package which provides logging integration for ASP.NET Core applications using Serilog.
If you're willing to use Audit.NET for outputting to Serilog, you may proceed like this:
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseSerilog(config => config
        .Logger(ev => Serilog.Log.ForContext(ev.GetType()))
        .LogLevel(ev => ev.Environment.Exception != null ? LogLevel.Fatal : LogLevel.Info));


